# Define own class list in dotnet

Tags: c#, json, .net

I need to define a class List in a dotnet (C#) project. I know that it will clash with the built in List<> but I need to define my own.

The issue: one of my weather providers has in their definition of the json response a node called list.  Translating the json to a class results in the top container class having a List<List>weather, where the template parameter is their list structure not the generic one.

Comment: I'm not sure what difficulty you're having. You can absolutely make your own class named `List`. Can you show the code you've done so far, and highlight what exactly the problem is?

Comment: `List` and `List<T>` are not the same name. There will be no clash. Are you saying, without actually saying, that your class needs to be generic as well? If so then you just need to qualify the name of the standard class when using it in code.

Comment: Note that the names of classes in C# don't really have anything to do with the names in JSON. You could call it "Bob", but so long as the property name is "List", the serialization will still work.

Comment: C# is case-sensitive so list ≠ List

Comment: Serialisation is based on properties name. The type has no effect. And List will not conflict with anything. https://dotnetfiddle.net/NjwWa7. I will recomend using any tool to generate the class base on a valid json. There is one build in Visual studio , special paste. But https://app.quicktype.io will do it too.